# Filtering a dataframe based on a sequence of variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe that has a sequence of variables, `c1...c20`. Each of these variables contain a code. I have a vector of codes, `code.vec`, and I would like to subset the dataframe to contain records where `c1|c2|c3|...|c20` are in `code.vec`.

Example data (only using 3 `cn` variables for the example):

```
code.vec<-c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4")

c1<-c("T1", "X1", "T6", "R5")
c2<-c("R4", "C6", "C7", "X3")
c3<-c("C5", "C2", "X4", "T2")

df<-data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
```

This is what I am currently doing:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(c1 %in% code.vec | c2 %in% code.vec | c3 %in% code.vec)

  c1 c2 c3
1 T1 R4 C5
2 R5 X3 T2
```

This works, but since the real dataframe has 20 `cn` variables, it becomes a lot of typing. It seems like there should be a simple apply or loop solution to this (and is easy to do in SAS using an array and a do loop) but I cannot work out a solution in R, and I can't find any similar questions on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `filter_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(. %in% code.vec))
```

**Result:**

```
  c1 c2 c3
1 T1 R4 C5
2 R5 X3 T2
```

Mentioned in the comments, if instead you want to filter on rows where *all* variables contain `code.vec`, you can use replace `any_vars` with `all_vars`:

```
df %>% 
  filter_all(all_vars(. %in% code.vec))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It figures there was a solution somewhere in the tidyverse that was much simpler than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @patward5656 `tidyverse` is indeed very powerful. As a side note, if you instead want to filter on rows where _all_ variables contain `code.vec`, you can do `df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. %in% code.vec))` instead.

Comment: This is one of the most under appreciated replies ever. It has one lone upvote, from me, and is awesome.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks, this answer actually helped me get my first golden badge :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that should be relatively fast.

```
# get the position of the rows that match using modulus (final row returns 0)
temp <- which(unlist(dat) %in% code.vec) %% nrow(dat)
# replace 0s with final row
temp[temp == 0] <- nrow(dat)
```

Then subset

```
dat[unique(sort(temp)),]
  c1 c2 c3
1 T1 R4 C5
4 R5 X3 T2
```

Note that I was working with character vectors in your data.frame variables. If you have them stored as factors you'll need to wrap `unlist(dat)` in `as.character()`.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(c1 = c("T1", "X1", "T6", "R5"), c2 = c("R4", "C6", 
"C7", "X3"), c3 = c("C5", "C2", "X4", "T2")), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2", "c3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```